# How can I use HttpListener when the url doesn't have ending by "/"?

Tags: c#, httplistener

I want to get listen to a url for getting some information. so my code is this:

```
public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    // Add the prefixes. 
    foreach (string s in prefixes)
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
    }
    listener.Start();
    //Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    // Obtain a response object.
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    // Construct a response. 
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // You must close the output stream.
    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] test = { "http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:8086/sms.html" };
    SimpleListenerExample(test);
}
```

The URL that I want to add as a prefix, has not ending by "/". and if I add it at the end of url, its not valid and doesn't work.

so how can I listen to a url that it doesn't have ending by "/" ??

Comment: In the URL the value assigned after `?` is  a query parameter. For example `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xxxxxx` where `www.google.co.in/search` is a URL and after `?` `q=xxxxx` is a query parameter. So, if your url also containing values like this then it means the url is containing query parameters.

Comment: What URI doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post an example of the prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

The url you supply is a prefix, so a handler for prefix http://xxx:8086 will match any requests that begin with that string, including http://xxx:8086/sms.html. This is the reason the prefixes have to end with "/", and it's described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want your listener to only listen to specific paths, you have to write some logic, and inspect what the URL in the request. To do that per request, you have to provide a callback to the httplistener, and inspect the request uri.

Here's a small program that returns 200 OK for http://localhost:8086/nisse.html and http://localhost:8086/kalle.html, but 404 for all other urls with the prefix 
http://localhost:8086/.

```
class Program
{
    private static HttpListener listener;
    static string[] uris =
        {
            "http://localhost:8086/nisse.html",
            "http://localhost:8086/kalle.html",
        };

    private static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;            
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        //Maybe not use exact string matching here
        if (uris.Contains(request.Url.ToString()))
        {                
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
            string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> YOU ASKED FOR:" + request.Url + "</BODY></HTML>";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
            context.Response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "NOT FOUND";
            context.Response.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {                 
        listener = new HttpListener();  
        //Add the distinct prefixes, you may want ot parse this in a more elegant way
        foreach (string s in uris.Select(u=>u.Substring(0,u.LastIndexOf("/")+1)).Distinct())
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var result = listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```